# Auto Layout Compatibility

Tags: layout

I thought I had a grasp on auto layout, but when I test it on my 3.5 iPhone it does not look like a UI should.

The question is in the Simulated Metrics What should the size of the device be ? Inferred , Freeform , Detail ??

Keep in mind I am building for all iPhone models 3.5 , 4 , 4.7 , 5.5...

Thanks much.

JZ

Answer (score 0):

I think, setting constrains through auto layout doesn't require you to concentrate on the Simulated Metrics. It could be freedom or fixed. What you need to know is your stimulator frame's size to calculate your component's contains.

For example, lets assume, you have an ImageView and you want that image view to consume 50% of your devices screen. You can use aspect ratio to do that but to calculate the ratio you need to know the stimulator's frame size.

If you select freedom, xCode will show you what is your stimulator's width and height. If it is 400X600 then you know that to be 50% of your screen size, your image view needs to be 200X300. So, you can then just go and set your constrains accordingly to make your image view look like 200X300 in your stimulator and then when you will test in any device, if you have set the constrains properly, you will have a constant behaviour.